# Spring Session with hazelcast session events firing

Tags: spring, hazelcast, spring-websocket, spring-session

I am using Spring Session with Hazelcast and Spring Websockets. As I don't need clustarization I use hazelcast with `MapSessionRepository`. But it doesn't fire event on session expiring or session deleting. What I want is to listen to `SessionExpiredEvent` and then disconnect user via websocket immediately. So I have two problems:

1. `MapSessionRepository` does not firing needed events (`SessionExpiredEvent` and etc.)
2. I don't realize how to send websocket notification using expired http session. I need something like `simpMessageTemplate.convertAndSendToUser()`.
   But how I can get the user?

So the only one variant I can see is to write own implementation for `SessionRepository<ExpiringSession>` with events firing. I hope you understood my question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Session Hazelcast support does provide publishing of session events. The functionality itself is implemented using `SessionEntryListener` so make sure you use [`@EnableHazelcastHttpSession` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#api-enablehazelcasthttpsession) which configures all the necessary components for Hazelcast integration.

It might also be of your interest that the upcoming Spring Session 1.3 (currently at `1.3.0.M2`) will provide [first-class Hazelcast support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/pull/544) with new [`HazelcastSessionRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.3.0.M2/reference/html5/#api-hazelcastsessionrepository) (which will, among other things, replace `SessionEntryListener`).

Comment: Thank you for response! And what about websockets? Does Spring automatically disconnect expired websocket sessions after http session expired?

Comment: I mean I want to use `simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser` to send notification to client via websocket about expired session, but can't imagine how to do it

Comment: Regarding WebSocket integration - yes, WebSocket sessions are closed on `SessionDestroyedEvent` (take a look at `WebSocketRegistryListener` which handles that). As for disconnect handling, I'd suggest you to take a look at [WebSocket sample](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/websocket.html) (located [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/1.2.2.RELEASE//samples/websocket) - hint: search for `WebSocketDisconnectHandler`).

Comment: Thank you a lot! I appreciate your help